# How to append a string to a tag with exiftool

Tags: exif, exiftool

Doing `exiftool -Comment='This is a new comment' dst.jpg` replaces any comment already present. How can I add the string instead?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that tool.. but could it be something as simple as using += instead of = ?

Comment: Nope, that's for adding items to a list-type tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:
`exiftool '-Comment<$Comment Stuff added to comment' dst.jpg`

Since you're copying a tag as well as adding stuff, you need to use the copy tag syntax "**<**" instead of the assign value syntax "**=**".

Comment: Thank you! I am actually trying to use it in a bash function, but I can't get arguments to work: `exiftool '-Comment<$Comment\n"$1"'` doesn't work. Can you help me please?

Comment: Solved. I had to write `'-Comment<$Comment$/'$1''`.